# How do TWIC, chessgames.com, chessbase, etc. keep up to date with new games?

Tags: fide, database

Most players use these services to keep up to date on the latest chess results, but how do these services source their databases? It would seem like a prohibitive amount of work to scrape results from various tournament websites, so is there an official source that everyone uses? If it's FIDE, I wasn't able to find it on their site.

Tournaments often have a place to turn in your scoresheets, but what happens between that and the game showing up in one of these databases?

Answer (score 2):

There's no official source for that. Someone just has to download the PGN games manually.

It is indeed a prohibitive amount of work, but we are talking about money here. They are **not** doing the collection for fun, they are trying to sell their services for something else such as paid membership or book advertisements.

Let's take a look at the TWIC homepage. Please note the paid ads by New In Chess. They're offering you PGN download as a business.

[image]

Comment: Download the games manually or use an application which crawls the web pages and downloads them automatically?

Comment: @Tom Manually is quicker in most cases. The olympid games are available on the official site.